# Magento CE Warning: simplexml_load_string(): Entity Parser Error

Tags: magento-1, system.log

I am trying to resolve an error I see in the system.log file for Magento. However I can not figure out what the issue or or more importantly how to resolve it. I have looked at the `update.php` file line 450 and do not see any incorrect code?

Below is the actual error I am seeing:

> Warning: simplexml_load_string(): Entity: line 12: parser error : Start tag expected, '<' not found  in app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Layout/Update.php on line 450
>
> Warning: simplexml_load_string(): </customer_account_create-->  in app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Layout/Update.php on line 450

Answer (score 0):

I think you have a mispelled/not well formed xml layout file somewhere in your magento

1. You can try https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11622995/check-xml-syntax-with-xmllint to figure wich file is "broken" and correct it
2. you coud also browse all xml files by looking for "customer_account_create" and check if someting is wrong, one by one
3. last tip si to add a debug temporary code in magento core function, like
   http://digitaldisseny.com/en/blog/72-magento-solve-xml-parsing-issues

one of theses 3 should work.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and just want to share my solution.

Use xmllint to go through all xml files and validate them. Run this command from the Magento root directory:

```
find -type f -name "*.xml" -exec xmllint --noout {} \;
```

This will print the validation results of the xml files on the screen. You will get some false positives like:

```
./app/code/core/Mage/CatalogInventory/etc/wsi.xml:2: namespace error : xmlns:typens: 'urn:{{var wsdl.name}}' is not a valid URI
```

But it should also print the xml file with the real error, in my case that was:

```
./app/code/local/Vendor/Module/etc/adminhtml.xml:23: parser error : Start tag expected, '<' not found
```

This error is thrown for example when the xml file has no real content like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!-- comment directly after xml declaration without any xml following -->
```